# error: found shape tag where item is expected

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

It gives me error on line number two showing "error: found shape tag where item is expected". It may be a problem of eclipse. I restarted eclipse and cleaned the project but nothing works..

```
<resources>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
  <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#515151"/>
  <corners android:radius="3dp" />
  <padding android:left="10dp" android:top="5dp"android:right="10dp" android:bottom="5dp" />
</shape>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Why you are using `<resources>` tag?***

Your code must be as

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
  <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#515151"/>
  <corners android:radius="3dp" />
  <padding android:left="10dp" android:top="5dp" android:right="10dp" android:bottom="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Read [this tutorials](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) about shape drawable. And [here is](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2011/07/19/android-shapes/) a demo application.

Comment: same error on line number one, i was not using resource tag before andi tried using resource but error exits in both the case.

Comment: I do not know it was showing me this error ""error: found shape tag where item is expected"

Comment: Now it does not show any error, it may be because of eclipse.

Comment: hey I got error... you removed space between android:top="5dp"android:right="10dp" of padding.... I updated in my answer

Comment: yes, I removed that how would i use at as for my table layout. I tried setting, android:background="@drawable/tableborders.xml"